# Erase C++ 2d vector row while doing calculations with the matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to simulate the mean behaviour of an ensemble of neurons. This means I need to do calculations with a matrix of a couple of billions of elements (`steps`~10<sup><sub>6</sub></sup>, `neurons`~10<sup><sub>4</sub></sup>).

To avoid eating my whole RAM (and dying trying) I decided to delete rows from the matrix as soon as I'm done doing calculations with it. I don't have too much experience with C++, but my understanding is that `v.erase( v.begin()-i+1);` should allow me to do so.

```
// Membrane potential matrix using st::vector
vector<vector<double>> v;
v.resize(steps + 1, vector<double>(neurons));
// Initialise v
for (size_t n = 0; n < neurons; n++) {
    v[0][n] = v0;
}

double v_avg[steps + 1] = {v0};

// Loop
for (size_t i = 1; i < steps + 1; i++) {
    for (size_t n = 0; n < neurons; n++) {
        if(v[i-1][n] >= vp) {
            v[i][n] = -vp;
        }
        else {
            v[i][n] = v[i-1][n] + h * ( pow(v[i-1][n], 2) + I[i] + eta[n] );
        }
        v_avg[i] += v[i][n]; // Sum of membrane potentials
    }
    cout << "step " << i << "/" << steps << " done\n";
    v.erase( v.begin()-i+1); // Erase row v[i-1]
    v_avg[i] = v_avg[i]/neurons; // Mean membrane potential
}
v.erase( v.begin()+steps+1 ); // Erase last row
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting segmentation fault after the `steps`/2 step (I'm doing tests with a small `steps` value):

```
...    
step 10/20 done
[1]    1791 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./qif_solve_vect
```

---

### Update:

Thanks to [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) I see what's my problem. My question would be:

1. How can I work with the matrix in a way it isn't allocated from the very beginning.
2. How can I deallocate/free rows whilst keeping the indices (unlike `v.erase( v.begin())`). This is essential, as I will later implement different refractory times for each neuron when they produce a spike (`v[i][n] = -vp;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `erase` statement, you're subtracting from `v.begin()`, which will result in an invalid iterator since it will point before the start of the vector.  You probably meant `v.erase( v.begin() + i - 1);`.

However, erasing like this isn't saving you any space since you already have the full matrix allocated.  The erase will move all the remaining elements down one element, and your indexing for the next loop will be wrong (since you'd want to use `v[0]` all the time).

Comment: Oh, I see. What would be the proper way to do it, then? (See my update).

Comment: @AlfredoHernández You could use `v[i].clear()` instead of the `erase`.  This would get rid of the row while keeping the indexing unchanged.  Your initial `v.resize` should use empty vectors, and your loop would need to populate each row before you start to use it.

Comment: I'm not too sure about how to resize `v` using empty vectors and how to populate each row (I guess using `push_back`). Could you help me with the code? Sorry to bother you.